# Make the boxes stay still when scrolling down using the scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

when I click a box, i can drag it around the screen. You can click the folder icon to open up information view, and a scroll bar will appear because there are a lot of text.

Problem: when i use my mouse to scroll the scrollbar, it also drags the boxes as well. How do I make it not move the box when I click the scroll bar to move the bar?

I am using `jsPlumb.draggable()` to enable dragging.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7PuN3/2/

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm not seeing this behaviour you've described in Chrome

Comment: firefox is what im using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stop/start dragging:

```
$(function(){   
$('#1 .button_wrap').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".info").html(newHtml).show();
    jsPlumb.setDraggable("1", false)


});});


$(function(){
    $("#1").on("click", ".info .ui-icon-close", function(){
        $(".info").hide();
        jsPlumb.setDraggable("1", true)
    });
});
```

then in your css add this class, not to let the div fade when dragging is disabled:

```
.ui-state-disabled{opacity: 1;}
```

Comment: do you know why the box seems more gray after making it not draggable?

Comment: @JennyC no, trying to figure it out :)

Comment: I think it might be a jsplumb thing

Comment: @JennyC I think hacking it this way, would work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7PuN3/6/

Comment: @jennyC discovered this issue, when disabling it is adding this class to the div: `.ui-state-disabled` fixed it by putting this class into css: `.ui-state-disabled{opacity: 1;}` check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/7PuN3/16/

Answer (score 0):

Quick look suggests to me, use relative or absolute positioning not fixed on button wrap. On my mobile it seems to work fine though.

Comment: Tried those 2 options, still  moves the box, im using firefox btw