# Make the scroll bar non draggable in jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I am using jsPlumb to set a box `draggable`, every time you click the folder-icon, a div named `.info` will appear displaying blah blah blah...

When I try to scroll the scroll bar, it moves the whole box. How can I prevent it from moving the whole box?

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/7PuN3/15/

BTW, you need to be using **Firefox**.

I made a post earlier: [Make the boxes stay still when scrolling down using the scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22535401/make-the-boxes-stay-still-when-scrolling-down-using-the-scroll-bar)  and someone suggested to use `setDraggable` to false, but the coloring changes to a faded color for some reason... Is there any other way to do this, or if I stick with the `setDraggable` to false, how do I fix the color fade?